# How to add the textviews equally in a Row?

Tags: android

i have  5 text views to be added horizontally,and it needs to occupy the displaywidth.When i change the screen orientation,it should change based on it.Is that can be done by Layout or it should be done programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Try using layout_weight parameter. Create a LinearLayout with layout_width="fill_parent" and layout_weightsum="5".

And then add 5 TextViews with layout_width="wrap_content" and layout_weight="1".

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by using `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` in your text view. This attribute specify that your text views will take up all the parent space in width.

**EDIT**

Hi..Table layout has a slightly different behaviour.

Quoted from [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html):

> The width of a column is defined by
>   the row with the widest cell in that
>   column. However, a TableLayout can
>   specify certain columns as shrinkable
>   or stretchable by calling
>   setColumnShrinkable()  or
>   setColumnStretchable(). If marked as
>   shrinkable, the column width can be
>   shrunk to fit the table into its
>   parent object. If marked as
>   stretchable, it can expand in width to
>   fit any extra space. The total width
>   of the table is defined by its parent
>   container. It is important to remember
>   that a column can be both shrinkable
>   and stretchable. In such a situation,
>   the column will change its size to
>   always use up the available space, but
>   never more. Finally, you can hide a
>   column by calling
>   setColumnCollapsed().
>
> The children of a TableLayout cannot
>   specify the layout_width attribute.
>   Width is always FILL_PARENT. However,
>   the layout_height attribute can be
>   defined by a child; default value is
>   WRAP_CONTENT. If the child is a
>   TableRow, then the height is always
>   WRAP_CONTENT.

hope this helps

**EDIT**

> When stretchable, a column takes up as much as available space as possible in its row

Suppose you have added the five textview in a column at index `col_index` in your table. This code will stretch the column.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="col_index"   
>
    ...

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Hello Sir, i added the Table layout and in it i added table rows,and in it and i addded 5 textviews,i set the 

android:layout_width="fill_parent" properties in table layout ,row and it is not working out
Any Ideas

Comment: How Can i do it in layout ,i saw those properties and how to set them sir?